# Can I get the default font size of a placeholder with python-pptx?

Tags: python, python-pptx

I'm creating a Powerpoint presentation with the [python-pptx package](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I know I can [set the font size](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html#applying-character-formatting) of a paragraph or a run. My issue is I want to set the font size *relative* to the default size. In other words: I need to know what the default font size of the placeholder is. Unfortunately `font.size` [returns None](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html?highlight=Font#pptx.text.text.Font.size) if no font size has been explicitly declared.

Here's what I expected to be able to do:

```py
from pptx import Presentation

# setup presentation
prs = Presentation()
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)

# make a title
title = slide.placeholders[0]
title.text = "Hello, World!"

# here I'd like to resize the font size to 70% of default
p = title.text_frame.paragraphs[0]
default_size = p.font.size # <= Desired behaviour. Returns None in reality
font.size = default_size * 0.7
```

Comment: You mention "placeholder" but no placeholder seems to appear in your code. Are you talking about "regular" shapes or placeholders (like title or body/bullets?)

Comment: My bad. Updated now with a more complete code example. Hopefully it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is somewhat complex and I don't have a recipe for you, but perhaps this will point you in the right direction.

In general, the font-size attribute for a shape participates in a *style hierarchy* similar to how Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) works. Values can be set at various levels and the closest explicit setting wins. This is why a shape-level setting is reliable, because it is the "closest" possible setting.

In the case of placeholders, like the title placeholder in your example, the cascade goes:

1. The placeholder shape itself (`slide.placeholders[0]` or more simply `slide.title`)
2. The *slide layout* placeholder this derives from
3. The *slide master* placeholder the layout placeholder derives from
4. Probably some global default when not specified in the slide master title placeholder

So to derive the *effective* font-size value you need to traverse this "inheritance chain" until you find an explicitly-defined value, which will be the effective value. Something like the following pseudo-code:

```py
def effective_title_placeholder_font_size():
    if title_placeholder.font-size is not None:
        return title_placeholder.font-size
    if slide-layout-title-placeholder.font-size is not None:
        return slide-layout-title-placeholder.font-size
    etc.
```

The process is further complicated by the fact font-size can be set on the overall shape, or can be overridden on an individual paragraph or run. This is the difference between selecting the overall shape and setting font size and selecting a range of text and setting the font size.

So you see something of the complexities involved. It's definitely doable, but you're going to need to want it pretty bad, depending on your Python and general software-development skill level.

At best, there is only partial API support for these various operations in `python-pptx` (like get the slide-layout counterpart of this slide placeholder, etc.), so you're likely to need to dig into the XML a fair amount.